# Rails ActiveRecord where clause not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I am using Mongoid with Rails. I have two models: A `sprint` and a `build`. A `build` has many `sprints`

sprint.rb:

```
class Sprint
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :build
end
```

build.rb:

```
class Build
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_many :sprints
end
```

In `sprints`, I want to get all `builds` that contain the current sprint, so I do:

```
def builds
    Build.where("sprint" => self)
end
```

And in my `show.html.erb` for `sprints`, I do:

```
<%= render @sprint.builds %>
```

However, I get an exception:

> `undefined method`**bson_dump**' for Sprint:0x007fd1acb68200

If I change the builds method to:

```
  def builds
    list = []
    Build.all.each do |build|
      if build.sprints.include? self
        list.push(build)
      end
    end
    list
  end
```

then everything works fine, and I get the intended results back. What could the issue be?

**Edit:**
I should also add that not all builds have sprints, meaning some builds might have a nil value for sprint.

Comment: can you please show the model contents?

Comment: it seems that a `sprint` can only belong to one `build`? So how can there be multiple `builds` for a `sprint`

Comment: @tihom hmmm good catch. It really should be a many-to-many relationship, such that a sprint has many builds and a build can belong to many sprints. Just not sure how to structure that.

Comment: look in `habtm` relationships ...[docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association)

Comment: @tihom mongoid supports this too?

Comment: Just googled and [this page](http://codecraft.io/2011/07/31/mongoid-multiple-many-to-many-relations/) might have some info

Answer (score 0):

The ActiveRecord `where` method is used to construct a SQL query. It doesn't know what to do with the `Sprint` object as a value in the hash. You need to look for some `Sprint` attribute, like the `id`.